# Replacing boilerplate code C# with inteligent methods (maybe by using pointers?)

Tags: c#

We are writing a data repository and we have a data model that has quite a few fields.
And on the top of that, we have data accessors that return requested field value of the data object with the given id.

However, the problem is that we have to write a method for every single field which results in a ton of boilerplate code that literally differs in the field accessed and sometimes the return value type.

Here is the code:

```
[Serializable]
struct MyItem
{
    public readonly int Id;
    public int SomeInt;
    public float SomeFloat;

    // in real-life scenario there are many more fields here
}

// we need this container because our JSON parser needs one
class MyItemDataList
{
    public List<MyItem> Items = new List<MyItem>();
}

class Example
{
    readonly MyItemDataList _myList = new MyItemDataList();

    public float GetSomeFloat(int id)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _myList.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            int currentId = _myList.Items[i].Id;
            if (id == currentId)
                return _myList.Items[i].SomeFloat;
        }

        return 0; // just so it compiles for the sake of this example
    }

    public int GetSomeInt(int id)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _myList.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            int currentId = _myList.Items[i].Id;
            if (id == currentId)
                return _myList.Items[i].SomeInt; // all of this methods differ only in the field accessed and value type returned
        }

        return 0; // just so it compiles for the sake of this example
    }

    // in real-life scenario there are many more fields here
}
```

One solution would be to write a switch (if-else) statement and simply in addition to id pass also the field requested but that gives us a very long switch and many comparisons (not a big deal but still).

Ideally, what I would like to achieve is some sort of a template method (maybe with use of pointers) that based on the field requested simply shift the pointer to the desired address and returns the bytes that correspond to the requested field. But how to do it in C#?

Comment: I am sure you are using the list as a dictionary. I would replace the fields against Properties and get rid of the GetSome* methods. Just put the Items in a dictionary with a proper Id and use `TryGetValue` to get the value. Or write an extension that uses `TryGetValue` and returns default if the was not found.

Comment: Why not just write a single method to return the `MyItem` with a given ID? Then a call to `foo.GetSomeInt(id)` would be replaced by `foo.GetMyItem(id).SomeInt`

Comment: We have to be able to return atomic values not only entire objects. That's the requirement sadly. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use generics and accept a `Func<MyItem, T>`. No need to use pointers, which are considered `unsafe` in C#.

```
class Example
{
    readonly MyItemDataList _myList = new MyItemDataList();

    public T GetSomeProperty<T>(int id, Func<MyItem, T> propertySelector)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _myList.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            int currentId = _myList.Items[i].Id;
            if (id == currentId)
                return propertySelector(_myList.Items[i]);
        }

        return default(T);
    }
}
```

Usage:

For example, if you want to get `SomeFloat`:

```
GetSomeProperty(someId, x => x.SomeFloat)
```

---

The method could also be implemented with LINQ:

```
public T GetSomeProperty<T>(int id, Func<MyItem, T> propertySelector)
    => _myList.Items.Where(x => x.Id == id)
        .Select(propertySelector)
        .FirstOrDefault()
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace the list against a dictionary.

```cs
public class MyItemDataList
{
    public Dictionary<int, MyItem> Items { get;} = new Dictionary <int, MyItem>();
}
```

Create an extension method that accesses the dictionary for convenience

```cs
public static MyItem GetItem(this Dictionary<int, MyItem> dictionary, int id) => dictionary.TryGetValue(id, out var item)? item : null;
```

Usage

```cs
var @float = Items.GetItem(2)?.SomeFloat ?? 0.0;
```